# Accessing methods from another class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, methods, ref

I am new to the C objective and I'm having lots of difficulties. Hope you goys would be able to help me out.

Alright, I have a view controller class that displays the data from the external sensor plugged to an iphone. I have another database class that is supposed to grab that data and store it in an array which  can be used to plot a graph.

I'm having difficulties in finding a way to capture the data captured by the view controller class method variables and using it to store in database class.

The code below is from View Controller class which captures analog signal and displays in UILabel.

```
(void) forceCalculationKg{
     NSNumber *number = [controller. analogInValues objectAtIndex:0];
     [controller enableDigitalInputs:YES]; 
     double value = [number doubleValue];
     double force; 
     force = 0.2908  *pow(2.718,(1.2089 * value));
     double forcekg;
     forcekg = force/2.2;
     forceoutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %0.1f", forcekg];
}
```

Comment: You'd need to alert your data class when the sensor class was finished pulling data.  You can do this by subscribing to an event thrown by the sensor class and then responding accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't submit code for this question that actually compiles. But in any case, I assume your forceCalculationKg method is the function on your controller that you are calling to retrieve the sensor data? You are then applying a calculation to the data and displaying it, right?. To keep this data around, just add a NSMutableArray property to your controller and save each transformed data point to it.

```
-(void) forceCalculationKg { 
     NSNumber *number = [controller.analogInValues objectAtIndex:0]; 
     [controller enableDigitalInputs:YES];  
     double value = [number doubleValue]; 
     double force = 0.2908  *pow(2.718,(1.2089 * value)); 
     double forcekg = force/2.2;
     [self.datapoints addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: forcekg]];
     forceoutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %0.1f", forcekg]; 
}
```

Where `datapoints` is a [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) property you add to your view controller via the @property and @synthesize keywords. You can then pass the `datapoints` array around  your program to wherever you need it.

Comment: Actually I haven't written code for the method that compiles. forceCalculationKg is from view controller class that takes analog signal through analogInValues and passes in variable value. What I want to do is write a method in another class that can use this variable and store it in NSMutable array to use to plot a graph.

Comment: Ok. Well the code I showed will work any place you choose to put it. Just remember to include a reference to the class in your view controller, or make the nsmutable array accessible in the other object via class level methods.